# Jsonip.com returning internal and external IP

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using http://jsonip.com to get the users IP address. For some users, its returning an internal and external IP as a comma separated string. I only want the external IP address. Can I assume some sort of order to the returned addresses? Is the external IP address always last? Or do I need to filter based on some criteria? For example: exclude 127.0.0.1, 192.168.*.*, 10.*.*.*?

```
$.getJSON('http://jsonip.com/?callback=?', function(data){
    console.log("Current IP Address: " + data.ip);
});
```

Comment: I've used this in the past reliably: http://checkip.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I never found this question until now. (I run jsonip.com)

jsonip uses the [x-forwarded-for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header to get the user's ip. The right-most (last) ip should be the visitor's public facing address.